# Need a formula for $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x), h(x))$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I know the derivative chain rule $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))= f^{\prime}(g(x))\cdot g^{\prime}(x)$.

What is the formula if $f$ is a function of two variables, i.e. what is $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x), h(x))$?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You need $D_1f,D_2f$ the "partial derivatives" of $f$. Then $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x),h(x))=D_1f(g(x),h(x))g'(x)+D_2f(g(x),h(x))h'(x)$. You need some "niceness" feature of $f$ beyond the existence of partial derivatives, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $f(u, v)$, $g(x)$, $h(x)$ sufficiently differentiable (what Thomas Andrews in his comment terms *nice*), taking

$u = g(x) \tag 1$

and

$v = h(x), \tag 2$

we have

$\dfrac{df}{dx} = \dfrac{\partial f(u, v)}{\partial u} \dfrac{dg(x)}{dx} + \dfrac{\partial f(u, v)}{\partial v} \dfrac{dh(x)}{dx}; \tag 3$

or, in terms of (1), (2),

$\dfrac{df}{dx} = \dfrac{\partial f(g(x), h(x))}{\partial u} \dfrac{dg(x)}{dx} + \dfrac{\partial f(g(x), h(x))}{\partial v} \dfrac{dh(x)}{dx}. \tag 4$

The above is simply an application of the multiple-variable ***chain rule***.  See [this widipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) for more.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ has as its derivative a matrix:

$$ f^\prime(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}\partial_1 f(x,y) & \partial_2 f(x,y)\end{bmatrix},$$

where $\partial_i$ denotes the $i$th partial derivative. This matrix is also called the Jacobi matrix (which is more general and applies for maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$). Note that this is only truly a derivative when $f$ is differentiable in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ sense - it is not always sufficient the partial derivatives merely exist.

Assuming $f$ is differentiable, the chain rule holds in a very similar way to how it does in $\mathbb{R}$, just with matrix multiplication instead of the scalar one:
$$(f \circ \phi)^\prime(x) = f^\prime(\phi(x)) \cdot \phi^\prime(x).$$

Define $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2: x \mapsto (g(x),h(x)).$ Assuming differentiability, 
$$\phi^\prime(x) = \begin{bmatrix} g^\prime (x)\\ h^\prime (x)\end{bmatrix},$$ and so:

$$ (f \circ \phi)^\prime(x) = f^\prime (\phi(x)) \cdot \phi^\prime(x)\\
= f^\prime(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}\partial_1 f(\phi(x,y)) & \partial_2 f(\phi(x,y))\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} g^\prime (x)\\ h^\prime (x)\end{bmatrix}\\ 
=\partial_1 f_1(g(x),h(y))\cdot g^\prime(x)+\partial_2 f(g(x),h(x))\cdot h^\prime(x)$$